# Min and Max Functions for a Tree

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that returns the min value in a tree.

The main problem is that I don't think that it really returns the min value and not just one random value of Leaf. Somebody said to me to use
`minBound`, but I didn't find information for this function, so I tried to write it myself. Would someone say me where the problem in my code is, and maybe how to use `minBound` instead of my function?

```
data MultTree a = Nil | Leaf a | Node a a (MultTree a) (MultTree a) deriving Show 
minTreeValue :: MultTree a -> a
minTreeValue (Leaf a) = a
minTreeValue (Node a b Nil _) = a
minTreeValue (Node a b left _) = minTreeValue left
```

Comment: Are you assuming that `MultTree` is always a search tree, with `minTreeValue left <= a <= b <= minTreeValue right` holding for all `Node a b left right`?

Comment: `minBound` isn't a function; it's the smallest value for a type that has a `Bounded` instance. You would only need that to define `minTreeValue Nil`. It's also only of use if `minTreeValue` has the type `Bounded a => MultTree a -> a`.

Comment: About the question - yes, this is the tree I want to analyze. But I still didn't understand what minBound exactly is. Would you mind explaining it a little bit more

Comment: It's just a variable. When you give a type a `Bounded` instance, you specify its smallest and largest values by assigning to `minBound` and `maxBound`. For example, `data Size = Small | Medium | Large deriving Enum`, you might define `instance Size where minBound = Small; maxBound = Large`.

Answer (score 6):

`minBound` is a name defined by the `Bounded` typeclass, to provide a common way of referring to the smallest element of a type. For example,

```
data Size = Small | Medium | Large deriving (Eq, Enum, Bounded)
```

Then `minBound :: Size == Small` and `maxBound :: Size == Large`.

---

It doesn't serve any use here. Even if `minTreeValue` required `a` to have a `Bounded` instance, the smallest value in a given tree `x` has little relation to the smallest value the tree *can* have, aside from the obvious `minTreeValue x >= minBound`.

---

Your definition is optimized for a tree which you know has the binary search property, which says that given a value `Node a b left right`, then

```
minTreeValue left <= a <= b <= minTreeValue right
```

In general, the tree might not have this property, in which case you always have to explicitly compare two values to get the smaller one. This requires a further
constraint on the type: `a` must have an `Ord` instance.

```
minTreeValue (Leaf a) = a
minTreeValue (Node a b left right) = minimum [a, b, minTreeValue left, minTreeValue right]
```

But, now we have a problem: `minTreeValue Nil` isn't defined. But there also isn't
a valid default to use in the recursion. You might *think* you could use `minBound :: a`, but that would be incorrect, because `minBound` is *not* the smallest value in any empty tree, as there are *no* values in an empty tree. As a result, you are forced to avoid calling `minTreeValue` on the empty tree at all.

```
minTreeValue :: Ord a => MultTree a -> a
minTreeValue (Leaf a) = a
minTreeValue (Node a b Nil Nil) = minimum [a, b]
minTreeValue (Node a b left Nil) = minimum [a, b, minTreeValue left]
minTreeValue (Node a b Nil right) = minimum [a, b, minTreeValue right]
minTreeValue (Node a b left right) = minimum [a, b, minTreeValue left, minTreeValue Right]
```

This is correct, but partial, as `minTreeValue Nil` is still undefined. You have to avoid calling it on `Nil`, even if such recursive calls have been avoided.

One solution is to change the type of `minTreeValue` to `Ord a => MultTree a -> Maybe a`, so that we can use `Nothing` for the smallest value of an empty tree. This also lets us easily ignore recursive calls that return `Nothing`. The `catMaybes` function lets us discard `Nothing` values from a list, then extract the values
from the remaining `Just` values.

```
import Data.Maybe

minTreeValue :: Ord a => MultTree a -> Maybe a
minTreeValue Nil = Nothing
minTreeValue (Leaf a) = Just a
minTreeValue (Node a b left right) = Just (minimum candidates)
  where candidates = a : b : catMaybes [minTreeValue left, minTreeValue right]
```

Comment: "You might think you could use `minBound :: a` [...]": Don't you mean `maxBound :: a`?  I know you are saying this doesn't work, but if you use `minBound :: a` as the base case for `Nil` then I would think that the `minTreeValue` of any tree containing `Nil` would be `minBound :: a`, whereas choosing `maxBound :: a` would mean all trees other than `Nil` produce the correct value.

Comment: I hadn't really thought about `maxBound`. True, that's the identity for the `min` operation (`min maxBound == id`), but it isn't really useful here. If the tree is empty, it's still wrong. If the tree isn't empty, you already two candidates in the root node